test function that includes another function
I try to test the function fetch_data which includes find_current_ip, but when run npm test, find_current_ip return undefined and spyFindCurrentIp has never been called.
In filter.js,
const os = require('os');
const http = require('http');
function fetch_data(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let hostname = find_current_ip()
        console.log(hostname)
        var options1 = {
            hostname: hostname,
            port: 10088,
            path:'/laxServer/getServerIp',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              'User-Agent': 'Apifox/1.0.0 (https://apifox.com)',
              'Accept': '*/*',
              'Host': hostname + '10088',
              'Connection': 'keep-alive'
            }
        }
        let options2 = $.extend(true, {}, options1)
        var req1 = http.request(options1, function(res1) {   
            var output1 = '';
            
            res1.on('data', function (chunk1) {
                output1 += chunk1;
            });
            
            res1.on('end', function () {
                let result = JSON.parse(output1)["result"];
                options2.hostname = result;
                options2.port = 2048;
                options2.path = "/query_cocs_info";
                options2.headers.Host = result + ":2048"
                var output2 = ''; 
                var req2 = http.request(options2, function(res2){
                    
                    res2.on('data', function (chunk2) {
                        output2 += chunk2;
                    });
                    
                    res2.on('end', function (){
                        console.log(output2)
                        resolve(output2)
                    })
                })
                req2.on('error', function (err) {
                    console.log('error: ' + err.message);
                    reject(err);
                });
                
                req2.end();

            });
        });
        
        req1.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('error: ' + err.message);
            reject(err);
        });
        
        req1.end();
    })

}
module.exports = {find_current_ip, fetch_data}

In filter.spec.js
const os = require('os');
const http = require('http');
const { find_current_ip, fetch_data } = require('../src/filter.js')
const filter = { find_current_ip, fetch_data }

        describe('fetch_F_A_data', () => {
            beforeEach(() => {
                jest.clearAllMocks();
                jest.resetModules();
            });
            test('fetch COC data', async() => {
                jest.mock('http')
                jest.mock('../src/filter', () => ({
                    __esModule: true,
                    ...jest.requireActual('../src/filter'),
                }));
                const spyFindCurrentIp = jest.spyOn(require('../src/filter'), 'find_current_ip');
                spyFindCurrentIp.mockReturnValue("mock_id")

                const mockRes1 = {
                    on: jest.fn().mockImplementation((event, callback) => {
                        if (event === 'data') {
                            callback(JSON.stringify({ result: 'mocked-result' }));
                        }
                        if (event === 'end') {
                            callback();
                        }
                    })
                };
        
                const mockRes2 = {
                    on: jest.fn().mockImplementation((event, callback) => {
                        if (event === 'data') {
                            callback('mocked-output2');
                        }
                        if (event === 'end') {
                            callback();
                        }
                    })
                };
        
                const mockReq1 = {
                    on: jest.fn(),
                    end: jest.fn()
                };
        
                const mockReq2 = {
                    on: jest.fn(),
                    end: jest.fn()
                };
        
                const mockHttpRequest = jest.fn()
                    .mockImplementationOnce((options, callback) => {
                        callback(mockRes1);
                        return mockReq1;
                    })
                    .mockImplementationOnce((options, callback) => {
                        callback(mockRes2);
                        return mockReq2;
                    });
        
                http.request = mockHttpRequest;
                const result = await fetch_data();
                expect(result).toBe('mocked-output2');
                expect(spyFindCurrentIp).toBeCalledTimes(1);
                expect(http.request).toBeCalledTimes(2);
            
            })
        })

    })



